# Why is \r messing up my string in Node but not browser?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I have a file (`test.js`) with these two lines:

```
const message = "2020-12-04T15:46:46.330Z\td441cf4d-7533-5876-8eac-970929202a0a\tINFO\t[AWS sqs 200 0.031s 0 retries] sendMessage({ MessageBody:\r   '{}',\r  QueueUrl: 'https://www.test.com',\r  DelaySeconds: 5 })";
console.log(message);
```

When I run this from Chrome, jsfiddle, etc it outputs correctly. When I run `node test.js` it outputs this:

`DelaySeconds: 5 })/www.test.com',1cf4d-7533-5876-8eac-970929202a0a    INFO    [AWS sqs 200 0.031s 0 retries] sendMessage({ MessageBody:`

It seems to move around characters based on `\r`. This output I get from the default AWS SDK logs so I'm not in control of the output before this point. In fact, I am trying to make it readable for our logs, and this glitch is in the way.

Removing `\r` makes things work as expected and outputs this:

`2020-12-04T15:46:46.330Z   d441cf4d-7533-5876-8eac-970929202a0a    INFO    [AWS sqs 200 0.031s 0 retries] sendMessage({ MessageBody:   '{}',  QueueUrl: 'https://www.test.com',  DelaySeconds: 5 })`

Comment: ```\r``` and ```\n``` are the same thing but on different systems. ```\r``` = CR (Carriage Return) → Used as a new line character in Mac OS before X
```\n``` = LF (Line Feed) → Used as a new line character in Unix/Mac OS X
```\r\n``` = CR + LF → Used as a new line character in Windows

Comment: @kmp that is accurate, but I'm on a Mac looking at raw log responses in Splunk so I flat out see the `\r` in the text